# How to show an image popup when one clicks on an image thumbnail?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, gallery

I have created a Gallery View shortcode plugin. I wanna add an feature to that which is - Whenever someone clicks on any image in that gallery, that image should get open in a stylish popup window. Since I am seeking to add this feature to my own plugin, I can't even think to use another plugin.
I tried to understand the coding of some such plugins but couldn't figure out any proper way to do so.
Please suggest!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) enque thickbox on front end

```
add_action('init', 'myplugin_thickbox');
function myplugin_thickbox() {
    if (! is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('thickbox', null,  array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
    }
}
```

2) Add thickbox to all your images that are displayed by the_content();

```
function fb_add_thickbox($content){

    $content = preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?).(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|ico)"(.*?)><img/U', '<a$1href="$2.$3" $4 class="thickbox"><img', $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'fb_add_thickbox', 2);
```

sources: 
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-implement-thickbox-to-all-images-which-contain-a-refered-link
http://www.ultimatewebtips.com/how-to-use-wordpress-native-thickbox-support-in-front-end/

Comment: Why would i like to add another plugin with mine one? Doesn't it look stupid?

Comment: Rather I would appreciate if you can provide me the straight-forward code.

Comment: This code should do exactly what your looking to do. Are you refering to thickbox as "another plugin"? Because thickbox comes stock with wordpress...

Comment: I also fail to see where the above is not "straight forward code", look at the examples I gave you, they should give you an idea of what direction to look.